# Set DateTime (utc) to listitem (CSOM, SP2013)

Tags: 2013, client-object-model, timezone

How to set UTC timezone to a listitem's DateTime field without executing query each time?

This would be slow for many datetime fields and items:

```
var utc = DateTime.UtcNow;
var localTime = clientContext.Web.RegionalSettings.TimeZone.UTCToLocalTime(utc);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); // Slow!
listItem["DateTime"] = localTime.Value;
```

We are using SP2013

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually you don't have to, time will be saved in **Local** time when adding list item, so you could just specify time value like this:

```
listItem["DateTime"] = utc;
```

---

Another option would be to retrieve SharePoint time zone and explicitly convert time into Local time using *.NET Framework capabilities* when saving list item as demonstrated below.

```
//1.Retrieve SharePoint TimeZone
var spTimeZone = context.Web.RegionalSettings.TimeZone;
context.Load(spTimeZone);
context.ExecuteQuery();

//2.Resolve System.TimeZoneInfo from Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.TimeZone 
var fixedTimeZoneName = sptimeZone.Description.Replace("and", "&"); 
var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().FirstOrDefault(tz => tz.DisplayName == fixedTimeZoneName);

//3.Convert time
listItem["DateTime"] = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utc, timeZoneInfo);
```

Comment: SharePoint seems to store UTC of the given local time to the database so saving 4pm in UTC+3 timezone would get stored as 1pm. Thus we get 1pm when reading the value (var value = listItem["DateTime"]; // 1pm)

Comment: so.. I guess 'listItem["DateTime"] = utc;' would not save utc because sharepoint converts the value to utc before saving. Otherwise your answer seems to work great :-) can we be sure the replacement will always be valid?

Comment: Good to hear! Regarding whether convert from UTC or not, tested it with SharePoint Online and it seems it saves it in local time without any additional steps..

Comment: If you first save a value and then retrieve it, you will get a different value than you inserted: The value you get is converted to UTC, right? (on-premises at least it seems to work like this)

Comment: hmm..i get the same value when it saved first and later when it retrieved

Comment: Are you sure you don't have UTC+0 in the web's locale? I checked from database that SharePoint and saves the UTC value to the database (after internally converting the given value from web's timezone (which it expects client to give) to UTC). And on-prem SP2013 seems to do no conversions when client reads the value, resulting in client getting the converted UTC value.

Comment: I agree with thomius. On-premise seems always store time in UTC. Look at my case at http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/103814/in-sp2013-how-to-search-a-datetime-property-with-querystring

Comment: @thomius, for some reason i missed your last comment, just  checked my Regional Settings, timeZone is (UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US and Canada)

Comment: There's a minor issue with comparing the Display Names.  An example is that GetSystemTimeZones() gives me "(UTC-05:00) Bogota, Lima, Quito, Rio Branco."  SharePoint gives me "(UTC-05:00) Bogota, Lima, Quito"

Answer (score 2):

To get local time you can also you basic javascript Date functions.Try below:

```
var currentDate= new Date();
currentDate.toTimeString();//Result format: 01:59:36 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have set the time zone for the specific web application where you host your list. If it's not set (blank), SharePoint will use UTC.

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint saves the DateTime in UTC, so in order to retrieve the desired value you should save **DateTimeOffset.Now**.