# SharePoint DateTime issue when date is saved using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, csom, date-time, timezone

The timezone set in SharePoint Online is EST and when it is being saved to SharePoint using CSOM/ECMA script from location with UTC +5:30 timezone the date is reduced. Everytime we edit the time is reduced. What is the right way to save date to SP using CSOM? SharePoint OOTB save it as per the local timezone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the JavaScript methods like `getUSTDate()`, `getUSTHour()`, `getUSTMinute()`, `getUSTMinute()` to Get the Current UST date and Time. Please refer the [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Date.prototype_Methods)

Or you have to convert it manually using the below code

```
function convertToServerTimeZone(){
    //EST
    offset = -5.0
    clientDate = new Date();
    utc = clientDate.getTime() + (clientDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
    serverDate = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));
    alert (serverDate.toLocaleString());
}
```

Comment: but when we save to list it changes the time . Is there a format with which we can save using CSOM to list

Comment: Refer this Link. This would be useful http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/103698/set-datetime-utc-to-listitem-csom-sp2013

Comment: Are you trying to write "UTC"? Do that then.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `SP.RegionalSettings.timeZone` property from sp.js to get the server timezone. 
The LCID for the current context can be gotten directly from 2 variables:

```
//as an int
var lcid =_spPageContextInfo.currentLanguage; 
// or as a string
var lcid = SP.Res.lcid;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have privileges to comment so adding it as an answer. 
SharePoint stores the dates internally as UTC, so when you add any data you need to manually convert the time to UTC otherwise when added from a different time zone you'll always see a time difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out [SP.TimeZone.localTimeToUTC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246758.aspx) which actually converts your date-time as per the UTC DateTime.

```
var isoDate = SP.TimeZone.localTimeToUTC(yourdatefield).toString();
```

Refer [How to: Set a date with correct time in a SharePoint list item](http://spuser.blogspot.in/2012/08/how-to-set-date-with-correct-time-in.html)

All the best!!

Sharing is caring....